# Gerar PDF com Jasper e fazer download sem armazena-lo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jasper

Estou gerando um PDF com Jasper, vou mostrar a forma como está sendo feita.

Estou salvando no disco, armazenando o caminho no banco e depois fazendo download. Gostaria de saber como fazer para que no momento que eu clicar para gerar, ele gerar e já fazer download. Estou utilizando o file Download do `primefaces`.

Como fazer para ele antes não salvar, apenas fazer o download?

```
public void imprimirRelatorio(GeradorEdital[] g) throws IOException, ParseException {

// O g é o meu dataSource. 

private StreamedContent file;
HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
parametros.put("ID_EDITAL", edital.getIdEdital());
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

try {

    JRBeanArrayDataSource arrayDs = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(g, false);
    String caminhoWebInf = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
    String caminhoReports = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports");

    JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminhoWebInf+"\\reports\\Edital.jasper", parametros, arrayDs);

    String caminhoFinal = "\\edital"+""+edital.getTitulo()+""+edital.getDataCriacao().getTime();

    File pdf = new File(caminhoReports+caminhoFinal);
    pdf.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream arquivo = new FileOutputStream(pdf);

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(impressoraJasper, arquivo);

    edital.setSrcPDF("//reports/"+caminhoFinal);
    editalDAO.atualizarEdital(edital);

    edital = null;
    disciplinaBean.setDroppedDisciplinas(null);

    arquivo.flush();
    arquivo.close();


    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
         this.file = file;
    }

public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String caminhoWebInf = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(caminhoWebInf+editalSelecionado.getSrcPDF());  
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", editalSelecionado.getTitulo()+".pdf");  

    return file;  
}
```

**O botão no .xhtml:**

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" 
                icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">  
                             <p:fileDownload value="#{editalBean.file}" /> 
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Troque seu `FileInputStream` por um `ByteArrayOutputStream`; guarde o array de bytes gerado por ele, e depois use um `ByteArrayInputStream` no lugar do `FileInputStream`; desta forma, o processo todo vai ser realizado em RAM.

Tenha em mente, no entanto, que para relatórios grandes isso vai "devorar" a memória do servidor; pode vir a ser mais adequado usar `File.createTempFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode alterar o cabeçalho colocando:

```
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");//inline;attachment;
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + nomedegravacaodorelatorio + ".pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
            servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();
            facesContext.renderResponse();
            facesContext.responseComplete();
```

O comando "Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" no cabeçalho avisa ao browser que não é para salvar, diferente do response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"relatorio.pdf\"");  que neste caso o código pede para salvar o pdf. Espero ter ajudado.